# Define a jsp tag which can accept some extra attributes which are not declared in the tld file

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I want to define a jsp tag, which can accept some extra attributes which are not declared in the .tld file. Is it possible?

I want this because I want to define a `<cms:img>` tag, which will generate a html `img` tag. User can pass some attributes to it, but I don't want to limit user, I hope they can use it just as a normal html img tag.

For example, user can use this tag and pass some required information:

```
<cms:img id="111" />
```

Which will generate a html img tag as:

```
<img src="/show_images?id=111" />
```

All I need is a `id` attribute.

But user may treat it as a normal html img tag, and pass some extra attributes to it, like:

```
<cms:img id="111" width="100px" height="100px" style="..." more attributes .. />
```

I don't want to declare the other attributes in my tag, because there are too many, and user may have their custom attributes.

So I want to know: Can I just declare the `id` attribute in the jsp tag, but let it accept all the other undeclared attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. These are called dynamic attributes. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags5.html#wp89775:

> dynamic-attributes     (optional)
>
> Indicates whether this tag supports
> additional attributes with dynamic names. The value identifies a
> scoped attribute in which to place a Map containing the names and
> values of the dynamic attributes passed during invocation of the tag.
> A translation error results if the value of the dynamic-attributes of
> a tag directive is equal to the value of a name-given of a variable
> directive or the value of a name attribute of an attribute directive.