# How to use global HTML attributes like class, style, etc. in JSP custom tags?

Tags: html, jsp, jakarta-ee, custom-tags

after doing my first experiences with custom tags in JSPs I would like to ask this short (but probably tricky) question: Is there a way to use the global html attributes like `class` or `style` in my custom tags? If I just go ahead and try to put for example the `style` attribute into my custom tag in the JSP, I get an error like

```
Attribute [style] invalid for tag [SomeCustomTag] according to TLD
```

Which sounds reasonable, as this is not an attribute which I had declared in my TLD. But still: What if I want for example to position my custom tags using `style="top: 0px"` and similar? How I would achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use **dynamic attributes** to handle this :

> **JSP.7.1.8 Attributes With Dynamic Names** 
>  
>   Prior to JSP 2.0, the name of
>   every attribute that a tag handler accepted was predetermined at the
>   time the tag handler was developed. It is sometimes useful, however,
>   to be able to define a tag handler that accepts attributes with
>   dynamic names that are not known until the page author uses the tag.
>   For example, it is time consuming and error-prone to anticipate what
>   attributes a user may wish to pass to a tag that mimics an HTML
>   element. New to JSP 2.0 is the ability to declare that a tag handler
>   accepts additional attributes with dynamic names. This is done by
>   having the tag handler implement the
>   javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.DynamicAttributes interface. See Chapter
>   JSP.13, “Tag Extension API” for more details on this interface.

There is also information here :

- [Dynamic attributes in a jsp tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729595/dynamic-attributes-in-a-jsp-tag)
- [Define a jsp tag which can accept some extra attributes which are not declared in the tld file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289429/define-a-jsp-tag-which-can-accept-some-extra-attributes-which-are-not-declared-i)